# Best place for human population of 2 million?

Tags: environment, humans, technological-development, alternate-history, agriculture

As my previous question(s) was too broad, I've decided to ask only one part of it:

The situation: all of humanity in its beginning is on a single island roughly the right size to support 1/2/3 million people. For some reason (sea monsters, too much ocean, whatever reason you want) it is impossible to get to another land and colonize that. For another reason of your choice, once the population reaches about 2,000,000 infertility problems are widespread enough that the population doesn't grow, remains stable.

Where would you base this island in order to have the best set of natural resources (e.g. soil fertility, natural flora/fauna, climate)?

Comment: What do you mean by the "best set of natural resources?" I can put an island anywhere in the world and justify a majority of resources through the use of nearby volcanos, ancient meteor impacts, and migratory birds.

Comment: Try [Aogashima Island](http://whenonearth.net/live-inside-active-volcano-aogashima-island/) but probably you need to wait a bit longer for landmass to increase...

Comment: New Zealand.  Britain or Ireland also worked quite well for reasonably small populations.

Comment: @jamesqf Don't forget about Cuba, Madagascar, Sri Lanka, Taiwan, Sicily....

Comment: Are you looking for a real island, a fictional island in an ideal location on Earth, or an ideal island in a fictional world?

Comment: @Joze: All of those islands are too hot to live in comfortably!

Comment: @Frostfyre  - Really? I wasn't aware of that, thanks!

Comment: @Travis Christian - The second one, preferably.

Comment: NZ ! :-) ...............................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to grow a lot of food, you need rain and hot temperatures ,ideally all year round. If it was possible, I would choose an island with an equatorial climate. The climate of Indonesia would be very good to support large populations within a small area. It's possible to have 2 or 3 harvests per year with some crops like rice once you get settled.

As Frostfyre mentioned, having some volcanoes around would have enhanced soil fertility over time.

Comment: Adaptability is not a problem, since as OP states the people lived there all along.